# Best ways to secure access to Azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have 2 types of Azure functions:

- I have a front-facing function (Python) that I expect it to only be reachable from another Azure service (Azure Workbooks) via HTTP
- I have functions (HTTP triggers, Python & C#) that should be only reached by another function (which is a time trigger one and in Python).

I've been reading on Function access keys but I'm not fully understanding how to manage access levels between functions.

Or should this be handled by permissions?
In short, what are the best practices concerning :

a) Communication between Azure functions?

b) Communication between Azure services <-> Functions

Comment: There are several solutions depending on the scenario, and from your question, it's unclear whether you want to restrict at the network level or at the authorization level; could you please elaborate? There are multiple options you can use, including managed identities and Azure AD authentication (app registration). Explain your question with examples so that I can provide more information.

Comment: thx for your answer @vithalwadje. i'm interested in restricting at the authorization level. In terms of managed identities, i'm not sure i know how many i need, would i need a function <-> function MI, and a workbook <-> function MI also, or is it more granular?

Answer (score 0):

Communication between functions should happen by Message Queue IMHO. Network is not reliable on cloud.

About the other function, you should set authorization level to function and rotate the key once in a while.

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static IActionResult Run(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "products/{category:alpha}/{id:int?}")] HttpRequest req,
string category, int? id, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    var message = String.Format($"Category: {category}, ID: {id}");
    return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(message);
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#authorization-scopes-function-level

Another good tip would be place an Azure API Management in front and require Key on that too.

Comment: thx for your answer. it's noted for the queue, i'll think about it.
do you have an example concerning the authorization level and key rotation?

Comment: @Fares I edited my answer. Check the AuthorizationLevel enum inside HttpTrigger attribute